# Number of triangles in a shape

Tags: combinatorics

What is the best way to count all of the triangles in this shape?

I originally  thought to just use casework to go through the ones composed of $1$ triangle, then $2$ triangles, etc., but I still missed several triangles, getting a total of only $75$.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, I've found $85$.  If we call the three pentagons the major, the minor, and the demi, we have

- All three points on the major: $10$
- All three points on the minor: $10$
- Two adjacent points on the major, one on the minor: $15$
- Two diagonal points on the major, one on the minor: $5$
- Two adjacent points on the minor, one on the major: $5$
- Two diagonal points on the minor, one on the major: $15$
- Two adjacent points on the minor, one on the demi: $15$
- Two diagonal points on the minor, one on the demi: $5$
- Two adjacent points on the demi, one on the minor: $5$

Comment: You are right ! (+1) I counted in b) $3$ triangles, missing the one between a point on the minor + diagonal points on major. So actually the part b) of my answer should read $20$, and so total coincides with yours.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to list all of the possible shapes of triangles and count the total amount of each kind.

For example: The triangle that goes from one vertex of the pentagon to the the two vertices opposite of it is repeated 5 times in the big pentagon and 5 times in the little pentagon. 
You can also multiply triangles found in both pentagons by 2.

Hint: One pentagon has 35 triangles, use this to find the total number of triangles.

Comment: Perhaps you can expand on the number of "possible shapes"?   Or provide a count for one such shape, to illustrate your suggestion?

Comment: I added more description

Answer (score 0):

a) Each vertex of the major pentagon makes a triangle with other two : ${5 \choose 3} = 10$.
b) Each vertex of the minor pentagon makes $3$ triangles with two vertices on the major $=15$.
c) Each vertex of the major pentagon makes a triangle with $4$ couples of vertices of the minor $20$.

Same as above for the minor pentagon, except for point c) where the couple of internal points is only $1$.

So in total that gives $10+15+20+10+15+5=75$, and your answer looks correct, unless I also missed something.
 --- *amendment* ---
And in fact, I missed $1$ triangle in b), as the answer by *Briang Tung* let me realize: so the total of b) should actually read $20$, leading to $85$ triangles in all.

Comment: as there are 10 points, can't it be $\dbinom{10}{3}$

Comment: @Kiran No, because some of the points lie on a straight line (five sets of four points are thus arranged). Using your argument you would expect a set of four points to always produce 4 triangles (4!/3!), but if they were in a straight line you wouldn't get any (unless you counted 'degenerate' triangles with h=0).

Comment: @Penguino, thanks clarifying.